# **Warning: Failed to move file!** **Error** **Unable to upload file.**

Tags: joomla-3.4, file-upload, file-permissions

The error raises whenever I try to upload a file (image) via backend clicking the image button in the tinymce editor. I've also tried to upload going to media manager and it fails and this is the following error message: `

**Warning: Failed to move file!**
**Error**

**Unable to upload file.**
`
I also have set both components administrator logs and temp folders permissions to 777. Please help me to fix this bug.

Comment: Did you check the folder you were actually uploading to? Or the temp folder path could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check your upload user?

If you are conected with "root" user your files will be with user and group permissions from "root".

When you acess files in www you can have this problem because your enviroment uses user from host or nobody user.

I holpe this helps.

Comment: The OP mentions that he is trying to upload images from the backend.